# Magento 2 - Send data to jsTree with checkboxes on Back-office

Tags: magento2, backend

I want to add jsTree to admin back-office with my data,

Example of jsTree with checkboxes :

[image: jsTree of role permission Magento2]

I created the `requirejs-config` file and the js file on `web/js`, I want to send data from block to the tree, is there any method?

the code of js file on `web/js` :

```
$.widget('mage.rolesTree', {
    options: {
        treeInitData: {},
        treeInitSelectedData: {}
    },

    /** @inheritdoc */
    _create: function () {
        this.element.jstree({
            plugins: ['themes', 'json_data', 'ui', 'crrm', 'types', 'vcheckbox', 'hotkeys'],
            vcheckbox: {
                'two_state': true,
                'real_checkboxes': true,

                /**
                 * @param {*} n
                 * @return {Array}
                 */
                'real_checkboxes_names': function (n) {
                    return ['resource[]', $(n).data('id')];
                }
            },
            'json_data': {
                data: this.options.treeInitData
            },
            ui: {
                'select_limit': 0
            },
            hotkeys: {
                space: this._changeState,
                'return': this._changeState
            },
            types: {
                'types': {
                    'disabled': {
                        'check_node': false,
                        'uncheck_node': false
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        this._bind();
    },

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _destroy: function () {
        this.element.jstree('destroy');
    },

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _bind: function () {
        this.element.on('loaded.jstree', $.proxy(this._checkNodes, this));
        this.element.on('click.jstree', 'a', $.proxy(this._checkNode, this));
    },

    /**
     * @param {jQuery.Event} event
     * @private
     */
    _checkNode: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.element.jstree(
            'change_state',
            event.currentTarget,
            this.element.jstree('is_checked', event.currentTarget)
        );
    },

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _checkNodes: function () {
        var $items = $('[data-id="' + this.options.treeInitSelectedData.join('"],[data-id="') + '"]');

        $items.removeClass('jstree-unchecked').addClass('jstree-checked');
        $items.children(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    },

    /**
     * @return {Boolean}
     * @private
     */
    _changeState: function () {
        var element;

        if (this.data.ui.hovered) {
            element = this.data.ui.hovered;
            this['change_state'](element, this['is_checked'](element));
        }

        return false;
    }
});

return $.mage.rolesTree;
```